# SSRS Parameter Does Not Equal

Tags: ssrs-2012

I have a report I want to limit to either "Value1" or "anything but Value1".

This is driving me nuts, in the default values I have :

1. Value1
2. <>"Value1"

Any ideas please, this is in SSRS2012 standard Report Parameters setup - not anything fancy in T-SQL and has taken up 83% of my day at work :)

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Could you clarify what you're trying to do? What error have you gotten with your current approach?

Comment: I have a list of 4 digit codes, a mix of letters and numbers. I want my report to run on only 2 options, namely one of the codes (JLL1) or,alternatively, everything but that first code (JLL1).  I set a parameter up for JLL1 and that runs fine, the other option I set to <>"JLL1" but I get no data.  And sadly no error report or reasons for failure. ?

Comment: Have you confirmed if there is data? If it's in a database, I would maybe try and copy the value of the field that you're looking to exclude into your code. It looks like you might have a space in your conditional.

Comment: yes there is definitely lots of other data with various of these codes included- if i remove the parameter I get thousands of responses. i have a feeling it is the notation i am using to get <>"JJL1" i have tried !="JJL1" and ISNOT"JJL1".   Also I have the parameter type set to "Text" - could this have something to do with the problem?

Comment: Could you post example data?

Comment: will do tomorrow at work - if I don't pass out with frustration first!

Comment: Can't add screenshot. Will keep looking for answers thanks.

Comment: Where you able to find a solution to this problem?  I am having the same issue and it is taking up WAY too much time for such a (seemingly) simple task.

Answer (score 0):

Are you passing double quotes to SQL?  You could try tracing the query using SQL Profiler.